# no puedo ingresar a un a vista por error de token laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel

No puedo ingresar a mi vista de reset para contraseñas, estoy usan laravel 5.1 y el error que me sale es este:

> ErrorException in 799914cb6bd05b74dd298cd45e169be3 line 19: Undefined variable: token (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-imsur\resources\views\auth\reset.blade.php)

y mi `reset.blade.php` es este:

```
@extends('app')
    @section('content')

        <div class="contact-content">
            <div class="top-header span_top">
                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="" /></a>
                    <p>Movie Theater</p>
                </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="main-contact">
                 <h3 class="head">CONTACT</h3>
                 <p>WE'RE ALWAYS HERE TO HELP YOU</p>
                 <div class="contact-form">
                     {!!Form::open(['url' => '/password/reset'])!!}
                        <div class="col-md-6 contact-left">
                            {!!Form::hidden('token',$token,null)!!}

                            {!!Form::text('email',null,['value' => "{{old('email')}}"])!!}

                            {!!Form::password('password')!!}
                            {!!Form::password('password_confirmation')!!}
                        </div>

                        {!!Form::submit('Restablecer contraseña')!!}
                     {!!Form::close()!!}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endsection
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente el error te indica que la variable $token no está declarada en la vista. 
Cambia tu declaración de campo de token:

```
{!!Form::hidden('token',$token,null)!!}
```

Simplemente, por: `{!! csrf_field() !!}`

Blade se encargará de coger correctamente el token, transformarlo en un field hidden, etc...

Mas información del helper `csrf_field()` , para tu versión de Laravel 5.1 aquí:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-csrf-field

Un saludo.

Comment: thanks chaval seguire esa documentacion